# Determine if a given year is a leap year

Tags: ruby, if-statement, switch-statement, case

**UPDATE** The problem I was trying to solve required a bit more than the Date implementation, as it required a method to take into account both the post-1752 Gregorian and the pre-1752 Julian calendars' differing definitions of a leap year.

The following is my solution, which passed all my RSpecs and is a considerable improvement on the nested conditional I started with:

```
def leap_year?(year)

  gregorian_year = true if year >= 1752
  julian_year = true if year < 1752

  gregorian_test = true if year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0
  julian_test = true if year % 4 == 0

  case
  when gregorian_year && gregorian_test
    true
  when julian_year && julian_test
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I wrote a simple, ugly nested conditional to achieve the following:

To achieve the following:

Return "true" if the year meets the following conditions:

1. Is divisible by four
2. AND is not a century year (e.g.) 1900
3. UNLESS it is divisible by 400 (e.g. 400, 800, 2000)

I wrote an ugly nested conditional:

```
if year % 4 == 0
  puts "Divisible by four"
  if year % 100 == 0
    puts "Century year"
    if year % 400 == 0
      puts "Quad-century year, leap year"
      true
    else
      "Not a Quad-century year, not a leap year"
      false
    end
  else
    puts "Not a century year, leap year"
    true
  end
else
  puts "Not divisible by four: not a leap year."
  false
end
```

I tried to achieve the same with a case conditional, but it fails to detect the number **2016** as leap year:

```
case year
when (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
  true
when year % 400
  true
when year % 4 != 0
  false
end
```

Two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong in my case conditional?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Updated the answer to include `Date#gregorian_leap?` and `Date#julian_leap?`. Keep in mind that different countries made the switch from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar in different years.

Comment: Please don't include answers in questions (i.e., your "update"). If you have a solution, post it separately as an answer. (That's seen fairly often on SO.) Readers appreciate questions that are to-the-point, clear and succinct.They may then look at the answers, add a comment or answer or just move on to the next question, but they don't want to waste time by having to plow though extraneous material in the question itself. Have a look at questions with multiple upvotes and note their common characteristics.

Comment: You question, because it contains working code,is  better suited to SO's sister-site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where you would get suggestions for how to improve your code. SO's mandate is to help fix broken code and to suggest approaches to solving problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to determine if a given year is a leap year, that has already been implemented for you in the `Date` class as `Date#leap?`:

```
Date.leap?(2000)
#=> true

# Or, alternatively:

Date.gregorian_leap?(1900)
#=> false

Date.julian_leap?(1900)
#=> true
```

More info in the Ruby documentation: [Date#leap?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-leap-3F)

If you would like to build it yourself regardless, this should work:

```
def leap_year?(year)
  return false unless year % 4 == 0
  return true unless year % 100 == 0
  year % 400 == 0
end

leap_year?(2016)
#=> true
```

Comment: I personally find this version easier to parse in my head than a `case` statement, but that is of course subjective.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `year` from `case year` if your `when` arguments are all boolean:

```
  case
  when (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
    true
  when year % 400 == 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
```

You can check it works :

```
def is_leap?(year)
  case
  when (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
    true
  when year % 400 == 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

require 'date'

p (0..2050).all?{|y| Date.leap?(y) == is_leap?(y)}
# true
```

This variant might be a bit more readable :

```
def is_leap?(year)
  case
  when year % 400 == 0
    true
  when year % 100 == 0
    false
  when year % 4 == 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Finally, you could just write a single expression without any `if` or `case` :

```
year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
```

Comment: The last variant is more readable, but the penultimate one is very helpful too.  Thanks!

Comment: @Eric seems to be less enthusiastic about your antepenultimate solution.